# Fortran derived type with optional components

Tags: fortran, fortran90, derived-types

Is it right to have optional component in the derived type. For example, the variable 'fname_new' in the code snippet below. If not, what is the way around? I want to include 'fname_new' optionally depending upon whether the source is of type 1 or 2.

```
TYPE, PUBLIC :: species
  CHARACTER(LEN=12) :: spname
  CHARACTER(LEN=12) :: source
  CHARACTER(LEN=20) :: fname
  CHARACTER(LEN=12) :: field
  CHARACTER(LEN=20),OPTIONAL :: fname_new
END TYPE species
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the old and now obsolete Fortran 90?

Comment: yes, only fortran90!

Answer (score 2):

The number of components must be known at compile time so you cannot have an optional component.  However, you can have an allocatable component.  In your case:

```
type :: species
  ...
  character(len=:), allocatable :: fname_new
end type
```

A different approach would be to construct some sort of class hierarchy.  This would have the benefit of encoding information in types rather than strings.

Edit: As @VladimirF pointed out, this approach requires fortran-2003.

Realistically, If the `fname_new` component is really only be 20 chars long, then you won't save a whole lot of space by making it an allocatable.  On an  x86/64 bit architecture, the allocatable will be an 8 byte pointer and will force some sort of alignment on your type that will eat a few more bytes.  I might just leave it as a `character(len=20)`.

Comment: A remark is in order that it is not Fortran 90 but  2003.

Comment: It is quite possible to declare a type that has a layout that is unknown at compile time.

Comment: @IanH Do you have an example?

Comment: I don't know if this is what IanH means, but depending on how you define "layout", parameterized types could fall under that.

Comment: @francescalus I was thinking of "layout" in terms of size and alignment.

Comment: In which case, certainly that's an example: `type t(len); integer, len :: len; integer x(len), y; end type`.

Comment: @francescalus gets the star.

Comment: @francescalus I've edited the answer to be more precise.  Out of curiosity, have you ever used the `len` parameterization?  Looking through the examples in the modern fortran book, I don't see the advantage over an allocatable

Comment: I use length parameterization a fair amount (when not having to support compilers without the feature).  I can't go into it well in a comment, but if you can find a way to ask an on-topic question (could be tricky) then I'll happily provide details.